# FME Data migration for Feature class with Attachments: GN to UN

Tags: arcgis-pro, fme-form, data-interoperability, migration, utility-network

I am currently trying to migrate my Geometric Network (GN) system data to the Utility Network (UN) and would like to include attachments in the FME workbench. Currently, I have a workbench that successfully migrates the points, lines and polygons (Assets, domains, and attributes) to target UN features but I am not sure how to handle attachments.

The attachments would be mapped from the source tables to the new UN attachment tables. For example, hydrant attachment table would be migrated to Device attachment table

Can attachments be migrated using FME? What type of transformers and workflow needs to be utilized to move this type of data? I would prefer not to do this with a script. If there is a way to perform this process in ArcGIS Pro that is an option as well.

Comment: "Because attachments are handled by a relationship class, FME is capable of easily creating this sort of connection. However, both the relationship class and attachments table must be created in ArcGIS beforehand."  https://support.safe.com/s/article/writing-arcgis-geodatabase-attachments